# Would tf.upgrade.py work to update tensorflow files 0.x to 1.0.1 or does it only upgrade to 1.0 version

Tags: python, tensorflow, migration, upgrade

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration

Please help! I need to migrate to the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically the same thing. Most of the code is compatible there are only a few categories of things that might causes issues. But yes, **you can use it** to migrate. Just make sure that you then continue to follow along with any release updates to keep your code up to date!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the migrate script will not migrate **everything**, i.e. there will likely be some manual changes required!

When I upgraded last month, some API changes like `tf.unpack` become `tf.unstack` but more subtle changes like the position of the `axis=` argument in `tf.split` required more careful work. Good luck!